# incorrect display when using fish shell

Tags: terminal, fish, iterm

My Mac laptop displays weirdly when using fish shell as below.

[image]

It maybe has nothing to do with fish shell, but I can not figure out what is going on.

the ENV: macOS sierra + iterm2(or terminal) + fish 2.4.0

It looks like this in Terminal

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insufficient information. What is `TERM` set to? In any event this is probably a question for the Fisherman developer and user community. It simply uses the fish `set_color` command which works fine AFAIK. If `set_color` is misbehaving please [open an issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/new). My best guess is that you've tweaked the default color pallete that iTerm2 is using. If you press [command-i] and click the "colors" tab does it show something like this: [image]

None of the fish developers, including myself, use Fisherman or Oh My Fish so we're not going to be much help with either. However, if you can reproduce the problem with just basic fish commands like `set_color` we'll be more than happy to help.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right, I'll look into the fisherman color settings. To be more specific, I am using Solarized dark Color Theme for iTerm2. I have 2 Mac laptops which were kind of being set in the same way. The private laptop displays well, but this company one doesn't. Not only in iTerm2, but also the company one does not have the blue color background, which is correct.

Comment: The "Solarized Dark" iTerm2 color theme isn't compatible with the colors being used by your fish theme. Notice that in Terminal.app the colored text is black on a bright blue background. The iTerm2 color theme you're using has a black background so black text won't be visible. Also, it redefines the bright blue to be the grey that you're seeing. If you switch to the "Light" iTerm2 color theme I'll bet the results look a lot more like what you're seeing in Terminal.app.

Comment: Also, if `fisher` is using the standard fish color variables compare the output of `set | grep fish_color` on your two systems. I'm pretty confident they aren't identical.

Comment: The fish color variables of the two systems are indeed not identical.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently. You can simply set the following variable color:

`# Background color for matching quotes and parenthesis
set fish_color_match <your_color>`

It will probably affect other things but for now (2 months) I haven't seen anything problematic with that.